# Twitter4J: get todays tweets from a public profile?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm aware you can get all tweets and the last X number of tweets but how would I return every tweet for the past 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Twitter Search, you can specify a date range using `since:` and a `from:` parameter to select who it is coming from. For example:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search?from=biz&since=2011-05-04&until=2011-05-05&rpp=20
```

Using Twitter4J, the query you want to use is the string `from:biz since:2011-05-04` using one of the search libraries.